# Is there any acceptable way to chop/recombine Django querysets without using the API?

Tags: django, list, django-queryset

I was to forced to use a models.CharField to store some additional flags in one of my models. So I'm abusing each letter of the field as a flag. As an example, 'MM5' would mean "man, married, age above 50"  and 'FS2' "female, single, age above 20".

I'm using methods to query/access these flags. Of course I cannot use these methods with the queryset API. I'm using list comprehensions calling the methods to filter an initial queryset and transform them into a plain list, which is good enough for most template feeding:

```
people = People.objects.filter(name__startswith='J')  
people_i_want = [p for p in people if p.myflags_ismale() and p.myflags_isolderthan(30)]
```

So, is there any ok'ish way to retransform these lists back into a queryset? Or to chop/filter a queryset based on the output of my methods without transforming it to a normal list in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be needlessly complicated as well as bad practice to try and "re-transform" your list back into a QuerySet, the best thing to do is to use cleverer QuerySet filtering.

You should use the queryset filter by `regex` syntax to get the functionality you need. [Documentation here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex).

For instance the equivalent to `ismale()` using `regex` would be something like...

```
People.objects.filter(myflags__regex=r'.M.') # <-- For matching something like 'MM5'
# Please note I haven't tested this regex expression, but the principal is sound
```

---

Also, while I'm admittedly not a database guru, I'm fairly certain using this sort of "flags" in a charfield is a rather inefficient way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

If you must convert a list back into a queryset, then the idiom I use is:

```
People.objects.filter(pk__in=[x.pk for x in list_of_objects])
```

Obviously, this hits the database again. But if you really need it.